# Permutation Questions assuming that each letter can appear at most once in an arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Assuming that each letter can appear at most once in an arrangement, how many ways are there to arrange 10 letters taken from the alphabet a-z such that:

Exactly one of a and z appears in the arrangement?

z and a appear and are adjacent to each other in the arrangement?

For the first one, my current answer is 24!/15! as it would be 1 in the first spot which is locked up by a or z, then 24 letters left to go into 9 more spaces, decreasing by 1 each time due to no duplicates.

For the second, I thought it would be az, which could go into 5 spots so 5!, then 24!/16! in the remaining 8 spots, but that seems too large.

Answer (score 1):

The first question:

> How many ways are there to arrange $10$ letters taken from the alphabet a - z such that exactly one of a and z appears in the arrangement?

You have not taken into account whether a or z has been selected or where it is located.

Choose whether a or z appears in the arrangement.  Choose which of the ten positions it occupies.  From the remaining $24$ letters (other than a and z), choose which will fill the leftmost open position.  From the remaining $23$ letters (other than a and z and the other letter that has already been selected), choose which will fill the leftmost open position.  Continue until all ten positions have been filled.

> $$2 \cdot 10 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21 \cdot 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16 = 2 \cdot 10 \cdot \frac{24!}{15!}$$

The second question:

> How many ways are there to arrange $10$ letters from the alphabet a - z such that a and z appear and are adjacent to each other in the arrangement?

You have not counted the number of places where the block containing a and z could appear correctly.  Also, you have to account for the order in which the letters a and z appear within the block.

Since the block containing a and z has length $2$, it must begin in one of the first nine positions.  Choose where the block begins.  Choose whether a or z appears first in the block.  Choose the letters for the remaining eight positions from the remaining $24$ letters, starting with the leftmost open position.

> $$9 \cdot 2 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21 \cdot 20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 = 9 \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{24!}{16!}$$